# Create a folder loop with user prompts

Tags: bash

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, but I cannot find out how to do this for the life of me. I'm trying to create a loop to create folders with user prompts until the text command "end" is input. For example, I would input the folder name for my semester as "Spring 2019" and then create sub directories for each class. Every article I find for loops shows me how to create a loop on a set amount of folders, but nothing that will stop with an input. Can anyone point me in the right direction, unfortunately I have nothing to even start with so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not good with scripts, but I would base this on a `while` loop, and test the input variable for the word 'end'  This article [https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-while-loop/](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-while-loop/) explains the process, and has an example using a file read.

Comment: You can `break` from a `while` loop based on the result of a [case statement](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Choices_.28case_and_select.29)

Answer (score 0):

Following script read folder name and create it in a loop. You can exit entering empty folder name, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. It will also create nested folders if input like "aaa/bbb/ccc".

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
  read -p "Folder name:" input
  [[ -z "$input" ]] && break
  mkdir -p "$input"
done
```